# specify unique key for mysql table in the JSON object

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am implementing an app that creates the JSON String below. The app records the JSON data and send it in the background to the server every 60 seconds. The user can use the app to query the server for the  buses locations, the result will be displayed  in google map with marker.

The data of  JSON will be first inserted in the `bus` table and then updated with `INSERT INTO`. In the bus table I do not have any `UNIQUE` key so I should add someone `bus_id` to the JSON string  in the app to know which record must be updated so I am asking myself whether is it possible to generate it and then add it to the JSON string before sending it. How can I generate `bus_id` UNIQUE key in my case?

JSON object:

```
{  
 "latitude":84.16898451,
 "longitude":3.16561387,
 "route":45
}
```

PHP script.

```
<?PHP

$json = '{"bus_id": "gernerated value", "latitude":84.16898451,"longitude":3.16561387,"route":45}';

$data = json_decode ( $json );

$bus_id = "it should be generated in the app";
$route =   $data->{'route'};
$latitude = $data->{'latitude'};
$longitude = $data->{'longitude'};


require 'connection.php';

// check whether route's table exist.
$results = $con->query ( "SHOW TABLES like 'bus' " ) or die ( mysqli_error () );

if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {
  //"UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2"
 $sql = "REPLACE INTO bus(bus_id, route, latitude, longitude)
          VALUES( ?, ?, ? , ? )"; 
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$bus_id,$route, $latitude,$longitude);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();

  echo "Table exist";
} else {
  $create =  "CREATE TABLE bus
       (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        bus_id INT(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        route int(11) NOT NULL,
     latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL , 
     longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
     created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)" ;
   $stmt = $con->prepare($create) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();

  echo "table was created";
}
```

Comment: There are lots of way to achieve this , you can try with the date as simple as you can like `date(dmyhis)` this will give you unique value always. it's only one way.

Comment: @Hardy: but the date(dmyhis) the timestamp  will change every seconds also it can not be uniqui for the records?

Comment: each bus have it's unique id? i mean it's not updated any more?

Comment: Every network device has a unique MAC address. This is what is used when creating GUIDs, hash the MAC address along with the timestamp. So each bus which has a network connection already has a unique identifier. It is just a question of whether that mac address is available to your application. We take it that you are trying to track the buses and not the passengers of course.

Comment: @Hard: do you mean timestamp for on seconds once and then I have to it to the JSON string? I thought  timestamp for each second.

Comment: @David the app based on crowdsourcing so I think it is good option.

Comment: @David what is purpose of hashing the timestamp to MAC. Is the mac not enough for my case?

Comment: @The Time, I was just explaning how GUIDs workas validation of my approach. For your needs the MAC address is good enough. It identifies the bus and the gps identifies its location. Users get to see where the bus is on your map in real time.